# What does a comparator consume compared to an ADC

Tags: adc, comparator

Is there a way to calculate the power consumption of a comparator for one single measurement? I would like to compare the power consumption of a comparator with the power consumption of an ADC. I expect the comparator to be able to measure faster and consume less by doing so.
However, I looked into multiple datasheets and could not find any data about power consumption. Why is that? How can I calculate it?

// EDIT:
In order to prevent myself of asking an A-B question here, I want to state my intent with this question: I want to show, that comparators are faster and less power consuming than ADCs while beeing cheaper overall. This is not about special chips but more a general thing I want to know. Therefore I just googled for datasheets instead of looking for specific ones because I am new to this area.

Comparator Datasheets I found or were linked in the comments are:

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv3501.pdf
https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/ts881.pdf

Comment: "I looked into multiple datasheets and could not find any data about power consumption" can you provide a link to those datasheets? I would be baffled if you can provide even just a single example from the sketchiest of the manufacturers.

Comment: I simply googled it and took what I got. e.g. this one: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv3501.pdf

Comment: In Table 6.6, it says *Quiescent current, typically 3.2mA@5V*. That's what the chip consumes. To that, add the current coming from the load capacitance.

Comment: @Janka So I would come out at 16mW?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please realise this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with a schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome.

Comment: @TonyM I know exactly what StachExchange is about and try to ask my questions to my best knowledge and only after I put much effort into trying to find the solution myself. I do not plan to design anything nor do I missuse this forum as encyclopedia. My knowledge regarding comparators is just limited so I am unsure which data I can trust and need more experienced people to help me out.

Comment: Great to hear. But there's a distinct lack of basic technical data such as part numbers in your question. I hope you'd agree that's bare minimum information and it's missing. Please edit it into your question rather than adding it in comments.

Comment: "power consumption of a comparator for one single measurement" - comparators don't take measurements, they .. compare, and they do it continuously.

Comment: Also, 3.2ma sounds huge; here's a more reasonable part from ST https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/amplifiers-and-comparators/comparators/low-power-comparators/ts88-line/ts881.html offering 210na

Comment: I think this question can only be answered with "it depends". An ADC is much more complex than a comparator. Many ADCs contain one or more comparators. I do not know of any comparator IC using an ADC inside. My point: a comparator is a much more simple block than an ADC. Then power consumption: that depends on IC manufacturing technology used, speed (faster generally means higher power consumption) and accuracy (for the ADC mainly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tongue in cheek answer:

An ADC has to include at least one comparator, or many comparators in the case of a Flash ADC. Here's a [SAR ADC](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/understanding-analog-to-digital-converters-the-successive-approximation-reg/):

[image]

Since the ADC has more circuitry than just a comparator, it will use more power! (all other things being equal, that is, if you could somehow buy the exact same comparator used in the ADC, which will never happen in practice...)

Now, the power used by comparators and ADCs depends on many factors so it's impossible to answer the question. One very important factor is speed: faster comparators use more power, because the input stage is essentially an analog amplifier, and high-bandwidth low-noise analog amplifiers require more current. So you will find slow micropower comparators using fractions of a µA, and superfast ones using several mA or even tens of mA. ADC power use also depends on speed, bits, etc.